# Stringifying $GeoLocation for the browser

Tags: string-manipulation, character-encoding

Currently, when I ask for

```
ExportString[{"geoLocation"->TextString[$GeoLocation]},"JSON", "Compact"->True]
```

I get this: `{"geoLocation":"40.11Â°N 88.24Â°W"}`

Will a browser or Javascript remove those Â symbols, or do I have to do anything extra to omit them?

Comment: I get the same thing you do, and I'm not very familiar with JSON, JavaScript etc, but I don't think this is the result we should get from this conversion. I think that extra character in there is the product of a bug somewhere deep inside the conversion functions. I would report this to Wolfram support.

Comment: It should also be noted that it has nothing to do with JSON; `ExportString[TextString[$GeoLocation], "Text"]` gives the same thing. I don't think you should pass around the text representation anyway, try `conv[GeoLocation[{lat_, lng_}]] := 
 ExportString[{"a" -> {"lat" -> lat, "lng" -> lng}}, "JSON"]` (call it with `$GeoLocation // conv`) instead and create the textual representation when you have to and not before.

Comment: That is what I'll do (referring to both of the above comments)

Comment: @Pickett what about an answer? :) p.s. What about `TextString[$GeoLocation] // URLEncode // URLDecode`?

Comment: @Kuba Done. Sorry for taking so long, keep up the great work :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `ExportString` has a problem with those characters. It is not limited to JSON:

```
ExportString[TextString[$GeoLocation], "Text"]
(* Out: "57.72Â°N 11.97Â°E" *)
```

One way to solve it is to create a list formatted string from `$GeoLocation` before exporting it as JSON:

```
conv[GeoPosition[{lat_, lng_}]] := ExportString[{
   "a" -> {
     "lat" -> lat,
     "lng" -> lng
     }
   }, "JSON"]
$GeoLocation // conv
```

This correctly returns

```
{
    "a": {
        "lat": 57.72,
        "lng": 11.97
    }
}"
```

Also to be noted: Kuba's variant `TextString[$GeoLocation] // URLEncode // URLDecode` (see comments) does export the position as a string correctly for viewing it in *Mathematica*, but the problem of converting it to JSON remains.